# gradle can't compile google places API

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, google-places-api

Compiling the latest version works fine, but since my emulated device isn't on the latest google play version I have to compile an older version of the API

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.+'

returns an error

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/location/places/internal/zzw;

I have already tried to delete .gradle and I don't use any other google API

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.beust:klaxon:0.30'
    compile("org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.0") {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
    }
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.+'
}
```

Since I can compile the latest version, it works on my own (real) android device

Comment: try to add this **compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'** in gradle

Comment: @Harshad just compiling that doesn't do anything

Comment: Shouldn't you just update your emulator rather than trying to use old versions?

Comment: because *all* emulated devices have an older version of google play so my code doesn't work and it pops up an alert " you must update google play blabla"

Comment: @rotten_flesh than why don't you update your google play!!? i think its may be a dependency version error.

Comment: Because you can't just do that on emulators, unfortunately.

Comment: @rotten_flesh have you tested your code in real device??

Comment: it works on my actual device since it has the latest google play version but it takes way more time to build the apk

Answer (score 0):

Update gradle to compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'

Comment: I don't need maps, I need places API

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'

Comment: doesn't work, same error on another file : Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceFilter;

Comment: add this lines to app gradle
    android {
            multiDexEnabled true
    }

    and add this dependency
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

Comment: Why are you recommending to **downgrade**?